# Why are my plots in matplotlib not showing the axes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am having trouble with my plots as the axes labels seem to show in Jupyter Notebooks when I was working on it.

However, when I exported the file to a .py file and ran it in terminal, the charts given do not have the axes labels..

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,5))

ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.set_title('Oil vs Banks Mean Return')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')

ax.plot(all_returns['Mean'], label = 'Banks Mean', color = 'green')
ax.plot(all_returns['Oil'], label = 'Oil', color = 'black')
ax.plot(movavg['Mean'], label = 'Mean MA', color = 'blue')
ax.plot(movavg['Oil'], label = 'OIL MA', color = 'red')

ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout();
```

In Jupyter Notebooks it shows the axes and labels eg. Year etc.:
[image: In Jupyter Notebooks it shows the axes and labels eg. Year etc.]

However, when I export it, they are gone:
[image: However, when I export it, they are gone]

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` might be the problem. Try `plt.show()` instead.

Comment: how do you export them? with savefig("Filename.png") ?

Comment: Could you please show the full code you use to produce the second image?

Comment: I think the line `ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])` is the problem -- it uses all figure space for the plot and leaves none for the axes. Try `ax=fig.add_subplot(111)` instead.

Comment: In jupyter notebooks, I just clicked on download as .py file, then I run that .py file in my terminal and the charts will show like the second pic.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Oh yes that makes sense. I tried it and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: @rcshon no problem. I formulated it as an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The line

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
```

causes the problem. Here you tell `matplotlib` to use all the figure space for the actual plot and leave none for the axes and labels. `tight_layout()` appears to have no effect if an `Axes` instance is created in this way. Instead, replace the line with

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and I will leave this solution also perhaps for me in the future.

The issue is with the subplot configuration tool
[subplot configuration tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCee6.png)

so, i just had to give more space to the display

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2,bottom=0.2, top = 0.9, right = 0.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this option:

```
color_name = "grey"
ax.spines["top"].set_color(color_name)
ax.spines["bottom"].set_color(color_name)
ax.spines["left"].set_color(color_name)
ax.spines["right"].set_color(color_name)
```